# How do you set search so it always restricts to relevant area?

Tags: 2007, search-scope

I've added a search box to my task list but it retrieves results from the entire site.  How do I set it up so that it will always just get results from the tasks lists.

I'm using the Advanced Search Box, but am willing to try others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring search scopes you can specify the content class.  A content class can specify a certain type of list, i.e. Tasks or even a specific list like a specific task list instance.

Here is a blog post I wrote about [Content Classes](http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/content-classes-in-sharepoint-search).